# What properties to choose for passing Classes to a function

Tags: ios, objective-c, pass-by-reference, incompatibletypeerror

I'm kind of lost in this subject of object properties. The Idea of my app is to have a number of functions in the ViewController and store them via pointer to function (*attack) in a Class (enemy). The Problem is passing objects by reference to this function.

two classes: enemy and player (NSObjects)

enemy.h

> ```
> @property void (*attack)(Class *enemy, Class *player, int); // synthesized
> ```

ViewController.h

> ```
> @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
>
> player *player1;
> enemy *monster1;
> }
>
> @property enemy *monster1;
> @property player *player1;
> ```

ViewController.m

> ```
> void attack1(enemy *attacker,player *target, int x) {
>
> target.health = target.health - x;
> NSLog(@"%i",target.health);
> }
>
> @implementation ViewController
> @synthesize player1;    
> @synthesize monster1;
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>
> [super viewDidLoad];
>
> self.player1 = [[player alloc] init];
> self.monster1 = [[enemy alloc] init];
>
> player1.health = 100;
> ```

The follwing two statements don't work:

> ```
> monster1.attack = attack1;              //Error 1 (yellow)
> monster1.attack(&monster1,&player1,20); //Error 2 (red)
> ```

**Error 1** says:  "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'void (*)(__unsafe_unretained Class*, __unsafe_unretained Class*, int)' from 'void (enemy *_*strong, player **_strong, int)'"

**Error 2** says: "Passing 'player *__strong *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained Class *' changes retain/release properties of pointers" (2 times)

I have tried permutations of putting __unsafe_unretained into the function in enemy.h or (nonatomic, assign) after @property but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1: `Class` is the type of *classes* not the type of any object *instances*. If you want to accept an instance of any class you can use `id` or `NSObject *` for the type.

Error 2: `monster1` is a variable of type `enemy *` (Note: classes by convention start with an uppercase letter, use `Enemy`) and will contain a reference to an instance of type `enemy`. The expression `&monster1` evaluates to the *address* of the `monster1` and is of type `enemy **` - a reference to a reference to an `enemy`. You should not be using the `&` operator.

There are probably other errors & design issues. You appear to have some misunderstandings about Objective-C, classes, objects, references and coding conventions; it might be a good idea to do some studying.

HTH

Comment: Thank you! The programm works (for now). And yes there's a lot to learn for me, I know :)

Comment: not only that, he is using `Class *`, which is a pointer to pointer to class object, so it's wrong on multiple levels